# Internet Connection Not Working

Tags: 12.04

My laptop is saying that it has connected to the internet in my house but every now and again a message box appears saying that it's disconnected and offline but yet in the network options it still says that im connected to the router in my home?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have had this problem before as well.

What you should try: Delete the network connection (from your history, so that it cannot reconnect automatically), turn off your wireless card, restart the system, turn back on your wireless card, and reconnect to your network.

Hope it works.